# ADB input text at email To field with separator does not accepted immediately

Tags: appium, adb, robotframework

I have a problem when automate the step to input email address (long list with email separator ; ) at Android Phone.

When perform this action manually, I do these steps:

```
At To field, use software keyboard, input abc@mail.com;cde@mail.com;efg@mail.com
```

the email address will be accepted the moment I pressed `;`
I could see the proper oval shape at each address which means email address is accepted.

When I use robot to automate it, I did not see the email address accepted like manual way.

```
*** Variables ***
${RECIPIENTS}         abc@mail.com;cde@mail.com;efg@mail.com;

*** Test Cases ***
Wait Until Page Contains And Click    ${TO-FIELD}
Run     adb shell input text '${RECIPIENTS}'
```

I have no idea how to make the automation step behave like manual way, is the way I construct Variable or test step wrong?

I can only able to enter text into the field by using adb shell input text.
The robot framework built in 'Input Text' does not accept by the device.

Answer (score 0):

You can try as follow and no need to give semicolon . Pressing enter will create a contact bubble and next email id can be given.

solo.sendkeys("abc@mail.com")

solo.sendKey(Solo.ENTER)

Comment: Am I need to import any libraries?

Comment: Also if I have a list of email address, how do I optimise the solo.sendkeys in for loop?

Answer (score 0):

Please let me know what automation frame work you are using ?

If you have list of email address please put in a list array and use any conditional loop

```
List email[] = {"abc1@gmail.com", "abc2.gmail.com"}

for(int i=0 ; i<=email.getSize();i++) {
solo.sendkeys(email.get(i));
solo.sendKey(Solo.ENTER)
}
```

This sample code helps you optimise the code in loop

Comment: i am using robot framework in pycharm python.